# Cant access external JS function in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, module, philips-hue

Hello i tried to programm my own GUI with HTML and JS for my Philips Hue Lights with huejay (https://github.com/sqmk/huejay).

When i try to use the JS function "LightOn()" from my main.js on a button in my HTML file there is an error:
"Uncaught ReferenceError: LightOn is not defined
onclick file:///C:/Users/noName/Desktop/Hue/index.html:1"

When i use the exact code for "Message()" from message.js it works correctly.

I converted `let huejay = require('huejay');` to `import { huejay } from "huejay";` is this correct? I know there is a problem with the import huejay in main.js but i dont know how to handle it correctly. I tried to set type="module" at the  Tag.

When i run the code manually from terminal everything works fine an my light turns on.

Please help ...

Here is my code:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hue Lights</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
    <button onclick="LightOn()">Light On!</button>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="message.js"></script>
    <button onclick="Message()">TEST</button> 
  </body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
import { huejay } from "huejay";

function LightOn() {

    // Client settings
    let client = new huejay.Client({
        host: '123.0.12.34',
        port: 80,               // Optional
        username: 'bridgeusername', // Optional
        timeout: 15000,            // Optional, timeout in milliseconds (15000 is the default)
    });

    // Test connection to the bridge
    client.bridge.ping()
        .then(() => {
            console.log('Successful connection');
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('Could not connect');
        });

        // Test authentication to the bridge
        client.bridge.isAuthenticated()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Successful authentication');
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log('Could not authenticate');
  });

  // Get bridge details and configuration
  client.bridge.get()
  .then(bridge => {
    console.log(`Retrieved bridge ${bridge.name}`);
    console.log('  Id:', bridge.id);
    console.log('  Model Id:', bridge.modelId);
    console.log('  Model Name:', bridge.model.name);
  });

// Save a light's attributes and state
  client.lights.getById(1)
  .then(light => {
    light.name = 'Living room';

    light.on = 1;
    light.brightness = 254;
    light.hue        = 32554;
    light.saturation = 254;

    return client.lights.save(light);
  })
  .then(light => {
    console.log(`Updated light [${light.id}]`);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log('Something went wrong');
    console.log(error.stack);
  });

}
```

message.js

```
function Message() {
    alert('External JS loaded');
}
```

Comment: Does the js file get even loaded from the browser ? 
You should server your files from a local webserver. Are you using any module bundler like webpack ?

Comment: No i dont use any bundler. I will try to use webpack. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add export in front of LightOn():

```
export function LightOn()
```

Read more:
https://medium.com/backticks-tildes/introduction-to-es6-modules-49956f580da

Comment: Hey thanks for your help. I tried to export but still the same error.

Comment: Try to change the script type to "text/javascript" instead of module. Just to see if you get another error.

Comment: You have declared the script as of type Module, but you are not importing it any where. That might be your problem. You'll need something like this: import  { LightOn } from 'main.js'; and then you'll also need the export I wrote about earlier.

Comment: Like this: ```<script type="module" src="main.js">import { LightOn } from 'main.js';</script>``` ?

Comment: Did you try to change the script type to "text/javascript" instead of module?

Comment: I have added an example to github, on how to do export / import of modules. https://github.com/mortengustafsson/Javascript-Module-import-export